# arc length of $\dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

how can I please calculate an arc length of $\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$. I tried to substitute $\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\sinh x$, which leads to $\int\sqrt{1+\cosh^2x}dx$, which unfortunately I can't solve.

Thank you very much.

C.

Comment: Assuming this is homework, are you sure the question isn't about $\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$?  That is one of the few examples where the arc-length integral can be done in elementary functions.

Comment: It was not a homework, I just found it somewhere on the web and tried to solve it. I know that $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ is easy to solve (as it leads to $\sqrt{\cosh^2 x}$), but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find Wolfram Alpha's solution a bit ugly, in that it returns complex results for a real entity, so I'll roll my own solution here.

We start with

$$\int\sqrt{1+\cosh^2 x}\mathrm dx=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int\sqrt{3+\cosh\;2x}\;\mathrm dx$$

which can be turned into

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int\sqrt{3+\frac{1+\tanh^2 x}{1-\tanh^2 x}}\;\mathrm dx$$

(recognize Weierstrass? ;) )

Let

$$\tanh\;x=\mathrm{sn}\left(v|\frac12\right)$$

where $\mathrm{sn}(v|m)$ is a Jacobian elliptic function, resulting in

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int\sqrt{3+\frac{1+\mathrm{sn}^2\left(v|\frac12\right)}{1-\mathrm{sn}^2\left(v|\frac12\right)}}\mathrm{dc}\left(v|\frac12\right)\;\mathrm dv=\sqrt{2}\int\mathrm{dc}^2\left(v|\frac12\right)\;\mathrm dv$$

where $\mathrm{dc}(v|m)=\frac{\mathrm{dn}(v|m)}{\mathrm{cn}(v|m)}$ is a Jacobian elliptic function.

From [this formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16.E21), we obtain

$$\sqrt{2}\left(v-E\left(\mathrm{am}\left(v|\frac12\right)|\frac12\right)+\mathrm{sn}\left(v|\frac12\right)\mathrm{dc}\left(v|\frac12\right)\right)$$

or, by undoing the transformation with $v=F\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)|\frac12\right)$,

$$\sqrt{2}\left(F\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)|\frac12\right)-E\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)|\frac12\right)+\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)\right)\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)\right)}\right)$$

which simplifies to

$$\sqrt{2}\left(F\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)|\frac12\right)-E\left(\arcsin\left(\tanh\;x\right)|\frac12\right)\right)+\tanh\;x\sqrt{1+\cosh^2 x}$$

to which an arbitrary constant can be added.

---

As an alternative, one can start with the *Mathematica* result

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{i}E\left(ix|\frac12\right)$$

and simplify (get rid of the complex stuff) accordingly, using the [second relation in formula 19.7.7 in the DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E7). Note that $\arctan\sinh\;x=\arcsin\tanh\;x$.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite too advanced for me, but I'll try to get it anyway.

Comment: @claudia: It admittedly is a bit "highbrow", but there really is no way to express the arclength function elementarily. (Also, I was looking for an excuse to practice my elliptic integral manipulations.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution for arbitrary integration limits in elementary terms: we face an [*elliptic integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral):

[Wolfram alpha output](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28sqrt%281%2Bcosh%28x%29%5E2%29%2Cx%29)

Comment: How can I fix my link?

Comment: I fixed the link. It's not necessary to introduce a html-tag, but it looks nicer. Some characters are not compatible with the markdown engine, in your case it was the offending `^` (this is where the link started to be broken). I replaced it by its percent equivalent `%5E`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @Theo, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried Wolfram alpha, but does it prove that simple solution does not exist? The plot of the integral seems simple enough.

Comment: It depends what you call simple: a single elliptic function is quite a simple solution (from one point of view). And yes, you can be sure that it cannot be reduced to $\sin, \cos, \exp$ and their inverses.